# How configure struts2 to get validation rules from Spring via @value

Tags: spring, validation, struts2

We are using spring 3 and struts 2. We use spring @value annotation to get values from property files.

We want to get validation rules from property files instead of hard-coding them in action.

Here is sample property

```
system.properties
transfer.account.min.amount=10
```

Here is the action:

```
public class TransferToAccount implements Preparable {

 @Value("${transfer.account.min.amount}") public String minAmount;

 //...........execute and other methods omitted

 @IntRangeFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.FIELD, min = "${minAmount}", key = "validate.int.min")
 public void setAmount(Integer amount) {
   this.amount = amount;
 }
```

The minAmount is populated correctly by value 10, but the validation is not working.

---

To see if parameters are passed correctly, I make a test as below.

Assume we want to get a key from spring managed property file ( This is just a test ;) )

```
system.properties
transfer.account.min.amount.key=validate.int.min
```

The resource bundle is:

```
validate.int.min = This field must be more than ${min}
```

...and we change validation as below:

```
 @IntRangeFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.FIELD, min = "${minAmount}", key = "${transfer.account.min.amount.key}")
```

Now when an error happens the validation message shows `validate.int.min`, instead of fetching this value from resource bundle!

Of course, when you run below code:

```
 @IntRangeFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.FIELD, min = "${minAmount}", key = "validate.int.min")
```

The error message is fetched resource bundle correctly!

---

If I can use annotation in this way, please let me know what is my mistake!

If I can not use annotations like this, please let me know what is the best way to avoid hard coding the validaiton rolls in actions.

Comment: What do you want to validate what spring is populated to the field?

Comment: I want to validate my form inputs. And, I want the spring framework populate the struts validations from property files. The form has a integer field which must be more than '10'. I want to get the '10' from spring @value and pass it to struts integer range validator.

Comment: You can validate using Struts validation framework the form when it's submitted. Also you can use Spring annotations to populate a bean when it's created. But you can't do both at the same time.